# undefined local variable or method `root_path' (Rspec Spork Guard)

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, guard, spork

I have a newbie question :-)

I'm "creating" an app, and I use M. Hartl's Tutorial to do so. But I have some problems since I decided to change my routes.rb.
I know the question has already been posted, but the answer doesn't work for me, so I supposed I should ask a new one...

Here are the codes :

### config/routes.rb

```rb
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
```

### spec/requests/static_pages.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  let(:base_title) { "Vidons" }

  describe "Home page" do
    visit root_path
    it "should have the h1 'Vidons'" do
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Vidons')
    end
    it "should have the base title" do
      page.should have_selector('title', :text => "#{base_title}")
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    visit help_path
    it "should have the h1 'Aide'" do
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Aide')
    end
    it "should have the title 'Aide'" do
      page.should have_selector('title', :text => "#{base_title} | Aide")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do
    visit about_path
    it "should have the h1 'A propos'" do
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'A propos')
    end
    it "should have the title 'A propos'" do
      page.should have_selector('title', :text => "#{base_title} | A propos")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    visit contact_path
    it "should have the h1 'Contact'" do
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Contact')
    end
    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      page.should have_selector('title', :text => "#{base_title} | Contact")
    end
  end
end
```

### spec/spec_helper.rb

(I removed one of the Rspec.configure block, and I kept the one that's inside the spork prerun block )

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

And here is the response of rspec-guard :

> 10:07:46 - INFO - DEPRECATION WARNING: The :version option is deprecated. Only RSpec 2 is now supported.
>
> 10:07:46 - INFO - Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications.
>
> 10:07:46 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
>
> 10:07:46 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
>
> Using RSpec
>
> Preloading Rails environment
>
> Loading Spork.prefork block...
>
> Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
>
> Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
>
> 10:07:53 - INFO - Spork server for RSpec successfully started
>
> 10:07:53 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
>
> 10:07:53 - INFO - Running all specs
>
> Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-rspec-2.4.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec"]...
>
> Exception encountered: #>
>
> backtrace:
>
> /home/flokate/Rubyrails/vidons/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:244:in `module_eval'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:244:in `subclass'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:230:in `describe'
>
> /home/flokate/Rubyrails/vidons/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block in '
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:244:in `module_eval'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:244:in `subclass'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:230:in `describe'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
>
> /home/flokate/Rubyrails/vidons/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3:in `'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
>
> /home/flokate/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
>
> Done.

Because of the DEPRECATION WARNING, I looked into my Gemfile, and removed the version's number, in order to use the last gems I'm interested to :

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'spork'
end
```

Which give me that :

```rb
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.6.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.12) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.12) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.12) 
Using mime-types (1.21) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.12) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.12) 
Using activeresource (3.2.12) 
Using annotate (2.5.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.6) 
Using ffi (1.3.1) 
Using childprocess (0.3.8) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Using websocket (1.0.7) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.29.0) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.2) 
Using coderay (1.0.8) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.7.7) 
Using rdoc (3.12.1) 
Using thor (0.17.0) 
Using railties (3.2.12) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using factory_girl (4.1.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.1.0) 
Using listen (0.7.2) 
Using lumberjack (1.0.2) 
Using method_source (0.8.1) 
Using slop (3.4.3) 
Using pry (0.9.12) 
Using terminal-table (1.4.5) 
Using guard (1.6.2) 
Using rspec-core (2.12.2) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.12.1) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.12.2) 
Using rspec (2.12.0) 
Using guard-rspec (2.4.0) 
Using spork (0.9.2) 
Using guard-spork (1.4.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Using libnotify (0.5.9) 
Using rails (3.2.12) 
Using rb-inotify (0.8.8) 
Using rspec-rails (2.12.2) 
Using sass (3.2.5) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5) 
Using uglifier (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

And it didn't change anything...
I don't understand much at this time, but I hope one of you will bring me the light ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to `visit root_path` inside a before block: `before { visit root_path }`

Comment: Thank you, it was as simple as you said ;-)

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't work for me; the only thing I've found so far is to restart Guard/Spork.