# Rspec undefined local variable or method root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, urlhelper

I'm starting to use Rspec, but when I run `bundle exec rspec` I get an error

```
 /spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local
 variable or method `root_path' for #<Class:0x00000102e46850> (NameError)
```

I do not have Spork or Guard running so the question below shouldn't apply

[undefined local variable or method `root_path' (Rspec Spork Guard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871918/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path-rspec-spork-guard)

I have added `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in my `spec_helper.rb` file, but that did not help.
[undefined local variable or method `root_path' Hartl's Tutorial Chapter 5.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240868/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path-hartls-tutorial-chapter-5-3-2)

Here's `pages_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'                                                                                                                                                       

describe "Pages" do                                                                                                                                                         
  describe "navigation" do                                                                                                                                                  

    def self.it_should_be_on(path_name, value=nil)                                                                                                                          
      before { visit path_name }                                                                                                                                            

      it "should be on #{path_name}" do                                                                                                                                     
        page.should have_link('Home')                                                                                                                                       
        page.should have_link('Inventory')                                                                                                                                  
        page.should have_link('FAQ')                                                                                                                                        
        page.should have_link('About Us')                                                                                                                                   
        page.should have_link('Location')                                                                                                                                   
        page.should have_link('Contact Us')                                                                                                                                 
        # page.should have_link('Login')                                                                                                                                    
      end                                                                                                                                                                   
    end                                                                                                                                                                     

    it_should_be_on root_path                                                                                                                                               
    it_should_be_on faq_path                                                                                                                                                
    it_should_be_on about_path                                                                                                                                              
    it_should_be_on location_path                                                                                                                                           
    it_should_be_on contact_path                                                                                                                                            
    # it_should_be_on login_path                                                                                                                                            
  end                                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

`spec_helper.rb`

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'                                                                                                  
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'                                                                                                                                                 
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)                                                                                                              
require 'rspec/rails'                                                                                                                                                       
require 'rspec/autorun'                                                                                                                                                     
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,                                                                                                      
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.                                                                                                                                  
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }                                                                                                         

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.                                                                                                                       
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.                                                                                                              
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)                                                                                                 

RSpec.configure do |config|                                                                                                                                                 
  # ## Mock Framework                                                                                                                                                       
  #                                                                                                                                                                         
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:                                                                                             
  #                                                                                                                                                                         
  # config.mock_with :mocha                                                                                                                                                 
  # config.mock_with :flexmock                                                                                                                                              
  # config.mock_with :rr                                                                                                                                                    

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures                                                                                              
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"                                                                                                                     

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your                                                                                               
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false                                                                                                
  # instead of true.                                                                                                                                                        
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true                                                                                                                                  

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred                                                                                                       
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of                                                                                                  
  # rspec-rails.                                                                                                                                                            
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false                                                                                                                 

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an                                                                                                 
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing                                                                                               
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.                                                                                                                              
  #     --seed 1234                                                                                                                                                         
  config.order = "random"                                                                                                                                                   
  config.include Capybara::DSL                                                                                                                                              
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers                                                                                                                       
end
```

**Update**
After reading about shared_examples, I tried this out successfully. Is there a better way to write this test? I ended up separating out the pages into individual pages like Home page etc.

```
require 'spec_helper'                                                               

describe "Pages" do                                                                 

  subject { page }                                                                  

  shared_examples "navigation" do |path_name|                                       
    before { visit send( path_name) }                                               

    describe "navigation links should be on #{path_name}" do                        

      it { should have_link('Home') }                                               
      it { should have_link('Inventory') }                                          
      it { should have_link('FAQ') }                                                
      it { should have_link('About Us') }                                           
      it { should have_link('Location') }                                           
      it { should have_link('Contact Us') }                                         
      # it { should have_link('Login') }                                            
    end                                                                             
  end                                                                               

  describe "Home Page" do                                                           
    include_examples "navigation", :root_path                                       
  end                                                                               
end
```

Comment: paths are not defined at the class level in specs

Comment: What do you mean? The paths are not defined in the navigations describe block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save your structure - you can change the code like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'                                                                                                                                                       

describe "Pages" do                                                                                                                                                         
  describe "navigation" do                                                                                                                                                  

    shared_examples_for 'main page' do |path_name|                                                                                                                         
      before { visit send(path_name) }                                                                                                                                            

      it "should be on #{path_name}" do                                                                                                                                     
        page.should have_link('Home')                                                                                                                                       
        page.should have_link('Inventory')                                                                                                                                  
        page.should have_link('FAQ')                                                                                                                                        
        page.should have_link('About Us')                                                                                                                                   
        page.should have_link('Location')                                                                                                                                   
        page.should have_link('Contact Us')                                                                                                                                 
        # page.should have_link('Login')                                                                                                                                    
      end                                                                                                                                                                   
    end                                                                                                                                                                     

    it_should_behave_like 'main_page', :root_path                                                                                                                                               
    it_should_behave_like 'main_page', :faq_path                                                                                                                                                
    it_should_behave_like 'main_page', :about_path                                                                                                                                              
    it_should_behave_like 'main_page', :location_path                                                                                                                                           
    it_should_behave_like 'main_page', :contact_path                                                                                                                                            
    # it_should_behave_like 'main_page', :login_path                                                                                                                                            
  end                                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

because "paths are not defined at the class level in specs"(c)
You cannot call path methods in spec class. It should be in `it` block.
And your structure is not perfect. It will be better to put code in modules and then include it, if you want to avoid the duplication.

Comment: I'm not set on keeping the structure, but I would like to avoid duplication. You suggested putting the code into modules, so what would a better structure be?

Comment: Edited. Blocks is not a good idea in such situation. shared_examples_for is better solutin, how Peter Alfvin suggested =).

Comment: Thanks for editing, I updated the question to show a solution I got working by reading both of your guys' answers. Similar, but changed the structure a bit. What you think?

Comment: Looking at your solution again, I think I like yours better because if I were to go down my path, then I would have write `include_examples` multiple times in each describe block. In your solution, I could write what a typical page would look like, ie nav and footer, then add `it_should_behave_like` to each describe block.

Answer (score 5):

None of the Rails helpers are available at the top level of RSpec's `describe` block. They are only available within the lower level blocks (e.g. `let`, `before`, `it`, etc.).

If you want to share code such as this across examples, you can use a shared_context or a shared_example, as described in the RSpec documentation, or switch to using symbols as parameters while at the `describe` level and defer interpretation of them as methods until you're within the lower level blocks, as shown in [the answer from @IharDrozdov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21211114/1008891).

Comment: This is the best explanation.