# Rails URL Helpers NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nameerror

Hey I'm new to Rails and Rspec and I'm just reading Michael Hartls Tutorial. I stucked at the point where I ran my static_pages_spec.rb

```
C:/Rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) i
n <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Class:
0x55795b0> (NameError)
```

static_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: heading) }
    it { should have_title(full_title(page_title)) }
  end

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }
    let(:heading)    { 'Sample App' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    let(:heading)    { 'Help' }
    let(:page_title) { 'Help' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    let(:heading)   { 'About' }
    let(:page_title){ 'About' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    let(:heading)   { 'Contact' }
    let(:page_title){ 'Contact' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end 
  describe "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('About Us'))
    click_link "Help"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Help'))
    click_link "Contact"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Contact'))
    click_link "Home"
    click_link "Sign up now!"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sign up'))
    click_link "sample app"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sample App'))
  end
end
```

I don't know what's wrong. I used this test ~20 times with "root_path" in it but it never did made trouble before.
If it's any useful, here my routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
    root  'static_pages#home'
    match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
    match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
    match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
        match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
    get "users/new"
end
```

I just looked after all the files I edited in the last 20 minutes but saw nothing that could explain this.

Comment: If you run rake:routes do you see a root path in there? You may need to do root to: "static_pages#home"

Answer (score 0):

> "You cannot call path methods in spec class. It should be in it block."
>   Check this out: [Rspec undefined local variable or method root_path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21211114/537648)